# Firebase Database ArrayList is not ordered

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Why is the list I retrieve from the Firebase Database not ordered with orderByKey()?

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
transactions = mDatabase.child("balance").child("users").child(userid).child("log").orderByKey();
transactions.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

        Map<String, Object> td = (HashMap<String,Object>) snapshot.getValue();
        ArrayList<Object> values = new ArrayList<Object>();
        values.addAll(td.values());
        Log.d("Transactions", values.toString());
    }

    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        // ...
    }
});
```

The ArrayList "values" is unordered.

This is an example of the structure in json format:

```
"balance" : {
    "users" : {
        "log" : {
            "-Kp0plO6zBeulHQ8S1Fj" : {
              "In" : 100
            },
            "-Kp0qHM73Mcwbli1gaK6" : {
              "Out" : -100
            },
            "-Kp0qgkORJx5sTi2rUZf" : {
              "In" : 100
            },
            "-Kp1OCdSpUA7SEZhVoPR" : {
              "In" : 100
            },
            "-Kp1OdtuuF6z_zlNj2St" : {
              "In" : 100
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the database structure

Comment: @AlexMamo added

Comment: And you want or order by which keys? This Kp0plO6zBeulHQ8S1Fj, Kp0qHM73Mcwbli1gaK6 keys?

Comment: @AlexMamo I want to order the values (+100, -65...) from Kp0plO6zBeulHQ8S1Fj to Kp1OCdSpUA7SEZhVoPR.

Comment: What is the key of  `+100`,  `-65` and so on? `+100`,  `-65` are only the values.

Comment: can you show database structure like json

Comment: @AlexMamo added the values.

Comment: @NguyễnTrungHiếu Added the JSON

Comment: "userid" is missing in the structure provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you retrieve a collection from Firebase, it receives three pieces of information for each child node:

1. the key of the child
2. the value of the child
3. the relative order of the child

When you call `snapshot.getValue()` in your current code, you tell Firebase to convert this into a `Map<String, Object>`. Since a `Map` is unordered, the Firebase client keeps the keys and values but loses the ordering of the children.

To ensure you keep the order, you must use `DataSnapshot.getChildren()` to process the result:

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
transactions = mDatabase.child("balance").child("users").child(userid).child("log").orderByKey();
transactions.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      ArrayList<Object> values = new ArrayList<Object>();
      for (DataSnapshot child: snapshot.getChildren)) {
        values.addAll(child.getValue());
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you want you need to change this line of code:

```
transactions = mDatabase.child("balance").child("users").child(userid).child("log").orderByKey();
```

with

```
transactions = mDatabase.child("balance").child("users").child(userid).child("log").orderByChild("In");
```

Comment: Thanks, but my list is still unordered; after using orderByChild("In").

Comment: Does all your childrens have the key `"In"` and not `"Out"` as in your JSON file. Because if there are different, the order won't work.

Comment: Yes, you are right. There is a child with another name. Is it possible to order that too?